# Quel mot quand on a une partie du crâne sans cheveux parce qu'on les a coupé ?

Tags: terminologie

Si je veux parler d'un homme (ou d'une femme) qui à une (ou plusieurs)  zone(s) chauve(s) sur le crâne, parce qu'il (ou elle) a coupé les cheveux qui se trouvaient à cette endroit, que dirais-je : "il/elle a les cheveux tondus" ou "il/elle a le crâne rasé" ou autre chose ?

Comment: Sans doute pas le cas ici, mais ça peut être bon à connaître : pour un moine, on dit "porter la [tonsure](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tonsure)".

Answer (score 1):

Si la peau du crâne est lisse on parle généralement de "crâne rasé". Si les cheveux sont coupés très courts (un millimètre par exemple), on parle plutôt de "cheveux tondus".

Comment: Justement je n’étais pas certain, je ne savais pas si c’était rasé ou tondu quand il n’y avait que quelques millimètres. Mais pour éviter toute confusion, j’ai trouvé un bon terme ! « Glabre » : là on est sûr que c’est lisse et peu importe la cause.

Comment: @gustav.b "Glabre", c'est pour les poils de la barbe, pas pour les cheveux.

Answer (score 1):

Si vous dites que le crâne est rasé, ce qui sera compris c'est que le crâne est entièrement rasé ; ça ne peut pas aller ; pourquoi ne pas utiliser les mots dont vous disposez et dire

- « plusieurs zones de son crâne sont rasées. » ?

Il ne faut pas appeler quelqu'un qui a le crâne rasé quelqu'un qui est chauve ; ne sont chauves que les personnes atteintes de calvitie.

Pour « chauve » le TLFi explique qu'il s'agit d'un crâne « Dégarni de cheveux » ; le dictionnaire de l'Ac. est plus explicite : « qui n'a plus de cheveux ou qui n'en a guère »; ne pas avoir de cheveux et avoir les cheveux rasés sont deux choses différentes: un cheveux rasé conserve sa racine, ce qui lui permet de repousser; c'est pour cela que pour réparer les ravages de la calvitie on peut parfois faire ce qui s'appelle des implants de cheveux.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour ces précisions.